# Necessary to empty my pellet grill auger when I'm done grilling?

Tags: grilling

So, I have a wood pellet grill. Is it a good idea to make sure there aren't any remaining pellets in my hopper or auger when I'm done cooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, I also have a pellet grill and we keep pellets in ours after we are done cooking but we also keep it covered and out of the weather.  I think the wood pellets could absorb moisture and expand if they get wet and possibly plug your auger.  :)